# Convert local datetime to UTC taking daylight savings into account

Tags: mysql, sql, timezone

I want to migrate an old database to a new structure used by a new app. The old database stored datetimes in local timezone. Thus all the dates and times are using time zones that were active at the moment of being saved. The time zone is not stored. Half of the dates are using standard time, other half is using daylight savings. Some are +1h and some are +2 hours. Thus I cannot simply use `CONVERT_TZ(dt, '+01:00', 'UTC')`. I have to detect the TZ of the stored datetime and use this TZ for convertion. Yes, this is not reliable possible on switching hours. But for the rest it should some how be possible.

I think about something like this:

```sql
-- Get time zone for base TZ 'CET' for given datetime
SELECT GET_TZ('CET', dt);
-- Return '+01:00' or '+02:00' (or 'CET'/'CEST')
```

How to convert all local datetimes to UTC using the correct local source time zone?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL supports [IANA time zone identifiers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).  Choose one that best represents the source of the data.  Keep in mind that several countries use "CET" and "CEST" as abbreviations, and not all of them have the same set of DST rules.

For example:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(dt, 'Europe/Berlin', 'UTC')
```

Comment: I already tried that but got always NULL returned by CONVERT_TZ. But it came out, I have to import these timezones before manually using mysql_tzinfo_to_sql. Now it works exactly like that and daylight savings are automatically applied.

Comment: Yes.  See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/time-zone-support.html#time-zone-installation